# Add animation to changing background image slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a background slideshow with thumbnails using the following sample code:

```
<div class="my-background-cover uk-animation-fade and uk-animation-kenburns" style="background-image: url({$product.cover.bySize.ats_large.url});">
```

When you click a thumbnail, the main image above is changed through JavaScript replacing the background-image url.

```
$('.js-thumb').on('click', (event) => {
      var quickviewDataBgPath  = $(event.target).data('image-large-src');
      $('.js-qv-product-cover').css('background-image', 'url(' + quickviewDataBgPath + ')' );       
    });
```

However, I tried to fade in and fade out as well as apply any animation I want to the background images as they changed. For example the css styles below were applied to the div using the classes `uk-animation-fade` and `uk-animation-kenburns`.

```
    'animation-name': 'uk-scale-kenburns';
    'animation-duration': '15s';
    'animation-direction': 'reverse';
    'animation-timing-function': 'ease-in'; 
    'animation-fill-mode': 'both';
```

However, the animation only work when the page loads and the first image comes up. When the thumbnails are clicked and image changes, the animation does not apply.
What is the right way to get each background image to fade in and out when clicking the thumbnails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're interested in here is css transitions as opposed to css animations. Plenty of resources online but here's an example:

https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/